# Getting Image from API, then storing it as Azure Storage Blob (image error)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-ad-graph-api

So I'm trying to do this:

1. Get Users from AD using Graph Api in a Azure Function (C# or Node)
2. For each user, get their photo, using Graph Api (in the same Azure Function)
3. With the photo data, upload as a blob to Azure Storage

Now, I have 1 and 2 working correctly. But now, I have no idea how to convert that image/jpeg string into a Blob in Azure Storage. I've tried a lot, researched a lot but it's been really difficult.

I've tried to use

```
blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
blob.UploadText(imgString);
```

But it doesn't work.

So my code looks something like this:

1. I get a fresh oAuth token from azure (good for 3600 sec)
2. Get /Users from AD Graph API
3. For each user, I use /user//photo/$value resource, which returns a image/jpeg data.
4. From that data (a string?) I try to blob.UploadText but it fails.

The way I'm getting the image data from GraphApi is using RestSharp, like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + email + "/photo/$value");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "image/jpeg");
return client.Execute(request);
```

So I return an IRestResponse, which contains something like this:

```
response.ContentType //to get the content type
response.Content // to get the body (the image)
blob.UploadText(response.Content);
```

And that's what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work, the file gets saved OK but when you open it, you can't really see the image. I think the issue might be some encoding, I've tried setting to different encoding types with no luck.

Take a look at this next picture. To the right, I got the image from Graph Api using PHP, and set header as image/jpeg, then echo the image data and that's it. It works. On the left, it's the Azure Function with javascript or c#, I get the image and when I try to do the same (show in the browser) I get a different binary string and no picture on the page (like if it wasn't image data), so it looks like as if the problem is encoding. I'm saving this binary data on a blob file with UploadText but it's not working.

[image: Encoding]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you get `Stream` or `byte[]` from step 2?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Please have to use **[RawBytes](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/IRestResponse.cs)** as blob content. It works correctly on my side.

```
blob.UploadFromByteArray(response.RawBytes,0,response.RawBytes.Length-1);
```

The following is my test demo code

```
var connectionString = "storage connection string";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = 
blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.jpeg");        
blob.UploadFromByteArray(response.RawBytes,0,response.RawBytes.Length-1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating another function using PHP as language. It worked as it should, but I will try your method to see if it works.